# how to find tab order of any UI in a windows application

Tags: c#, user-interface, window-handles

I want to be able to find out the tab order of any UI in 3rd party applications. Let's say in my application I have a window handle of a UI of some other application running on my system. I want to know the tab order of that UI in that application.

Example:

I am running Skype on my system. Let's say I have the window handle of the Call button available on Skype interface, and now I want to know what is the tab order of that button.

I am developing my application in C#. Is there any way to programmatically get this sequence number.

Answer (score 0):

If you do [EnumChildWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for a particular container window you should get the controls returned in tab order.